# dealloc not being called in hierachy of view controllers despite looks ok in Allocation Instrument

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I have `UIViewController`s `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` where `C`'s `dealloc` sometimes is not called for reasons I do not yet understand.

- This path will call `C.dealloc`: `A` presents `B`, `B` pushes `C`, `C` unwinds to `A`
- This path won't call `C.dealloc`: `A` presents `B`, `B` pushes `C`, `C` pushes `D`, `D` pops back to `C`, `C` unwinds to `A` (`dealloc` not being called now causes my app to crash for other reasons)

I thought the reason was that there was still some reference to `C` left after presenting `D`, which would cause a call to `dealloc` to be deferred. However, if I investigate with the Allocation Instruments I see only one persistent allocation of `C` before unwinding to `A` in both cases. It's presumably the one held by the navigation controller, so that looks alright.

How can I find out more about this (to me) strange discrepancy and solve the root cause?

**UPDATE** I have by now found out that the problem is the order in which `dealloc`s are called as a result of unwinding. I was assuming its `C.dealloc`, then `B.dealloc`, but it actually seems to be the other way round. (The presentation of `D` only is related insofar as it establishes a state in which the app depends on the order.) So the new question is: can I make any safe assumptions about the order of calls to `dealloc` is such a situation. (I'm e.g. registering/deregistering some KVO observers and notification handlers in `viewDidLoad`/`dealloc`).

Comment: I'm going with "NO" in answer to the update here.  No safe assumptions about the order, though certainly you can stop observing other objects in dealloc.

Comment: @stevesliva `NO` appears to be the right answer. I've now surrounded code in `C.dealloc` that caused the crash by `if (self.presentingViewController != nil)` (i.e. is it no longer displayed but not yet deallocated?) The (by now conditional) code reloads rows in `self.tableView` as KVO observer. Because of the ordering issue it can happen the call occurs after `C`'s table no longer exists, and this is now taken care of. That seems to work in my particular case.